# SQL Alchemy does not execute queries

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy to run a query in SQL Server.
The query is supposed to create a table.
The below example is meant to be easily reproducable for you.
It does not contain the actual queries I use.

If I run the following code no table gets created. No error or message of any kind is returned.
(Please assume the URL_OBJECT is created properly)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(URL_OBJECT, fast_executemany=True)

with engine.connect() as connection:
    connection.execute("Select 1 as an_integer into database.schema.test_table")
```

--> If the table "test_table" already exists I get an error telling me that the table already exists.

In contrast, the following is working:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(URL_OBJECT, fast_executemany=True)

with engine.connect() as connection:
    print(connection.execute("Select 1").fetchone())
```

Returns: (1,)

This one also does what it should.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(URL_OBJECT, fast_executemany=True)

with engine.connect() as connection:
    print(connection.execute("Select * datebase.schema.table_existing_in_database").fetchone())
```

Returns: That table's first row's data.

Why is my table creation code not executed while the Select statements are?

Comment: Are  you *sure* it's not being committed, rather than not run? Do you have auto commit enabled?

Comment: Re the "bonus question"; this should be a different question. Ask one distinct question in a question. Asking multiple *might* result in others voting to close your question as not focused.

Comment: @ThomA I removed the bonus question. If I wrap the query in "Begin Transaction;" and "Commit Transaction", there is no difference in outcome.

Comment: I'm not talking about the SQL, I'm talking from Python perspective. Normally auto commit, in Python, is *off*.

Comment: @ThomA Let me check this. I didn't know I have to activate auto commit in Python. If you want to speed up the process please tell me how to turn it on. I have to read the documentation of SQLAlchemy to learn it.

Comment: @ThomA: It was a problem with the commit. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit otherwise every transaction is rolled back by default.

SEE: [commit-as-you-go](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#commit-as-you-go)

```py
with engine.connect() as connection:
    connection.execute("Select 1 as an_integer into database.schema.test_table")
    connection.commit()
```

You can get more logging information by setting `echo=True` in `create_engine()`.  Maybe post that information from this example if committing doesn't solve this.

You should also wrap the sql statements in `text()` from `sqlalchemy.sql`.

Comment: This throws an "'Connection' Object has no attribute 'commit'" error.

Comment: The echo=True option returns the SQL statements executed but not the message generated by the SQL Server.

Comment: Is probaly due to the SQLAlchemy version being 1.4.39. Let me update it to the current version.

Comment: After the upgrade it worked.